# OAuthException Code:2 on specific servers only. Does facebook apply throttling/filtering by IP/country?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

We are doing app for facebook and for the moment we are working with payments implementation. The problem we are face now is that most of the time when we got the payment id we can't properly query it's details via Facebook Graph API. Most of the time it returns OAuthException with code 2.
And what is more strange that this happens only on the servers located in Ukraine, when we do the same request from server in France it works 100% of time.
So how is it possible that if I ussue the same command:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/310433089087390?method=GET&access_token=<accessforapptokenhere>"
```

on the the servers in Ukraine it gives 99% of the time:

```
{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}
```

and if I issue the same command on server located in France it gives correct object dump output ?

The more strange, if I use same Ukraine IP but query object in Graph Explorer facebook debug tool in my chrome browser it also works correctly all the time.

Anybody knows the reason why facebook gives me code:2 error most of the time ?

Thanks.

---

Refer to BUG: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/559637900741795